# Firebase facebook and gmail accounts are not merged

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When i sign in to my android app using gmail and facebook, two separate authentication credentials are created at firebase. Is it possible to merge them?

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign in the user using any authentication provider or method. (Assume your user have already Signed In with Google).
2. Get the credentials for the new Authentication Provider (Facebook).

`AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());`

3. Pass the `AuthCredential` object to the signed-in user's ``linkWithCredential``` method.

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            }
        });
```